# Why is the website suddenly weird? How can I permanently change it?

Tags: bug

The forum layout now looks like this: [image]

and I'm not sure why. How do I *permanently* change this back? I can disable it for a specific page by clicking the top 'clock' button - but whenever I navigate, after a few pages it reverts back to this layout, which seems to appear on both the main site and meta.  Furthermore, there are sparkles wherever my cursor goes, making the site incredibly slow.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the usual April 1st "joke"...

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's the 31st for me, but in saying that, I'm not sure StackExchange feels the need to employ this intrusive 'joke' - it's a formal Q&A site, after all. I've updated my question to ask how I revert this permanently rather than for a specific page.

Comment: Timezones... :/

Comment: [Same bug report on network meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely) about the turn-off button not being persistent (though somewhat rantily phrased).

Comment: @user574848 how can one be "intrusive" into one's own house and home?

Comment: All these unnecessary changes are indeed annoying. If this should be a joke, it is an extremely poor joke (and moreover too earyl) ! Why must everything that is currently good be turned into something terrible ? The recent layout change also was a very bad decision !

Comment: Related question: How can I keep this "skin" beyond April 1st?

Comment: @Peter (and all): not too long ago we had a discussion about the design, when the current design was new. I suggested that the new style elements express the desire of the non-mathematical developers to gain more attention (more boxes, reducing the netto-space of the math content and the overview, making the optic fancy instead of (s)t(ra)ight...) . That new idea with the happy horses (even if an april-joke) I take as a new indicator of this. The gui-developers seem to have boresome days, and no-one gives them reputation-points... Let's see where this gui-development goes in future.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I do not know how many users preferred the old layout. I was quite diasppointed that this change was actually done. The joke-layout is a catastrophe and I think that some users (including me) would not keep using the site.

Comment: @Peter - yes, sigh. Let's take a bet from when on the mathematics-netto-contents becomes below, say , 20 % of the brutto space of the page. 2021? Earlier than in wikipedia? 2020 might be a good year for this: *"The community of stackexchange announces the year 20-20 the year of 20% math-contents on its website"* or so... >;)

Comment: A solution given in [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely)

Comment: I agree that the forum layout looks really bad, though the sparkles wherever the cursor goes it's great :P .I wonder if one could have the option to switch to the current site but with the sparkles feature.

Answer (score -1):

The bug about the clock icon not disabling it site-wide now seems to be fixed.
[Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382051/please-dont-show-the-licorne-on-each-question/382067#382067).

Comment: It's unfortunately not fixed for me...

Comment: -1 it doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: (-1) it doesn't work for me too. On which observation did you do your statement, Henning? If I move to another SE-site, and open one question I've the little pony paradise as well to disable manually...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I base it on the observation that it works for me now -- site-wide as I wrote, not network-wide. If you disable it from one question on a site, do other questions on the same site still show the April fool's theme?

Comment: @Henning - ok, there's a unexpected misunderstanding. "Sitewise" I thought means over the site-of-stackexchange. (expecting they have some centralized management) . You have to unclick it in "math", "stats","buddhism","german language","buddhism" ... separately, whereever you read your Q&A-inputs... In each of them, after you have clicked it, you're in peace, {sigh}

Comment: @GottfriedHelms still better than having to do it for each question separately.

Comment: @Henning - that comment into the ear of a software-developer having developed discussion/mailing/chatting services via intranet in the 90ies: well, maybe this years now this might be a really noteworthy feature... <ahem,ahem> ;-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms it it's noteworthy because for the first hour or so *today* there was a bug that made the button work only for one question at a time.

Comment: @Henning - ah, I see, thanks for the clarification! (Well, let's stop this now).

Answer (score -1):

You see, after 640x480-screens we upgraded to 800x600 then 1024x768 and now 1920x1080 pixels. Just to see 5 thematic subjects on one screen-page...
[image]

But well, we're not happy with this. We need improvement.... We want at most that in the red box:

[image: image2]

I guess, 30 % of the screen-space for thematic contents?
I vaguely remember some freaks who constructed web-pages with 64x64 pixels or so for information... just a weird competition between nerds, I think ...

Comment: On 13 February 2005 I posted [a rant in sci.math](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.math/4ZqUK42eMIM/AJKooYsvYhYJ) (most of which is excerpted [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4540682), where it's probably easier to read), which you may have seen since I'm pretty sure you were a frequent sci.math participant at that time, about the various changes google and Math Forum keep going through for discussion groups. **(continued)**

Comment: Among other things, I said this: *But now the Math Forum has, for some reason, changed their site so that posts there are also virtually unreadable. Reading posts there is now like trying to read a book where 40% of the left margin of _every_single_page_ is reserved for the table of contents, publishing information, and other books by the same publisher.*

Comment: @Dave - yes I remember vaguely some ranting by you and as far as I remember I think I usually shared your position. The dynamics behind such deterioring processes are still some mystery to me, often it is accounted to some effects in developing bureaucracy ... but recently I heard about the epoch of "manierism" in fine arts - and what that latin word really intended to mean: a habit of that artists to include some special flair in their artwork to make it easily recognizable who the author was - the signing of the picture seemed to be too little prominent. Perhaps some rebirth of ideas here?